# looking for a javascript engine

Tags: javascript, c++, scripting

i'm looking for a js engine to that I can (easily) expose C/C++ functions, classes etc. The API should allow changing exposed values from within C++ (by storing some kind of pointer or reference to an object inside js or so...). I've considered using google's v8 but I'm new to it and don't know whether it will satisfy my requirements. Can someone tell me whether I should stick to v8 or try something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, V8 will work fine for you. Chrome Developer Tools invoke JS methods from the C++ backend, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I believe both chrome and firefox backend libraries offer methods to expose c++ methods to java script. give them a try